# An issue when passing a PHP parameter to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php

I the following code, I have a form that consists of three fields and two buttons. In the Review button, I would like to show any word in Arabic randomly and let the user show its translation in English by ticking the `Show translation` button.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
    function myFun1(var) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The translation in English is  " + var;
    }        
</script>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $english = $_POST["english"];
        $arabic = $_POST["arabic"];
        $example = $_POST["example"];
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="english" rows="4" cols="70" placeholder="English">English</textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea name="arabic" rows="4" cols="70" placeholder="Arabic">Arabic</textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea name="example" rows="4" cols="70" placeholder="Example">Example</textarea>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add new">
    <input type="submit" name="review" value="Review">

    <br>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</form>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "yyy";
$dbname = "vdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Vocabulary (English, Arabic, Example)
    VALUES ('$english', '$arabic', '$example')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
elseif (isset($_POST['review'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) as total FROM Vocabulary";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    #echo $row['total'];

    $generated = rand(1,$row['total']);

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Vocabulary where ID = $generated";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
    $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

    echo "<br>";
    echo $row1['Arabic'];

    echo "<br><br>";

    $eng = $row1['English'];

    echo '<button onClick = "myFun('.$eng.')">Show translation</button>';

}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

In the code, the following line creates the button and trigger the `myFun1()` function:

```
echo '<button onClick = "myFun('.$eng.')">Show translation</button>';
```

The problem is when the button is clicked, nothing happens (the message is not shown at all). Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: is there an error in console !?

Comment: You have `function myFun1(var)` but call `onClick = "myFun('.$eng.')"`?

Comment: @M0ns1f There is no error. The message is not shown at all.

Comment: can you show an example of $eng output !?

Comment: can you show a pic of your database?

Comment: The message can be something like `The translation in English is Play`

Comment: `var` is a reserved word in javascript. Name the argument something else

Comment: So are you going to address the `myFun1()` != `myFun()` issue?

Comment: @charlietfl the problem still there.

Comment: @Sean fixed it but still have the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly change the argument **var** to some another argument name as **var** is a keyword in javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFun(as) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The translation in English is  " + as;
        }        
 </script>
```

Secondly, you have to pass the **string value** in single or double quotes for that use inverted slash `\` and rectify the function name from **`myFun()`** to **`myFun1()`**

```
echo '<button onClick = "myFun1(\''.$eng.'\')">Show translation</button>';
```

Rest your code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You have definition of function myFun1(var), but you are calling myFun(). I guess this is the problem why there is nothing after clicking on button.

Comment: I fixed it but the issue is still there

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the top before

> < html > tag

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $english = $_POST["english"];
    $arabic = $_POST["arabic"];
    $example = $_POST["example"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Why does it need to be moved before the `<html>` tag? php is parsed before the html is output, so it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @Sean Is just a **header check** is **before any output** that the reason why when you use **header location** or **session** you got some error **"... sending by ouput"**, and this check **isn't a php parse** i don't see any **echo** inside the IF. Is also a bad pratice...

Comment: function myFun1(change_this_param_name_with_no_reserved_name) as @charlietfl  just tell you is 100% your error cos using reserved name.